# GIF do not animate when share on twitter

Tags: ios, image, gif

I am creating animated GIF file with `NSArray` of `UIImage`. And saving it in `NSDocumentDirectory` as well as in Photo Album of iPhone.

The problem I am facing is, when I open the saved GIF in Email Composer or in iMessage, it animates fine. But when i share it through twitter, it does not animate. I tried sharing through twitter app on iPhone and saw an Interesting thing(ScreenShot below) that The GIFs i downloaded from different websites using Safari shows a label 'GIF' on top left corner of GIF. While my saved GIFs does not. What might be the problem here? Can anyone please guide me.

[image]

Here is the code for creating the GIF file:

```
float delay = 1.0/15.0; // 15 FPS

NSDictionary *prep = @{
                       (__bridge id)kCGImagePropertyGIFDictionary: @{
                               (__bridge id)kCGImagePropertyGIFDelayTime: @(delay) 
                               }
                       };

//    static NSUInteger kFrameCount = 16;

NSDictionary *fileProperties = @{
                                 (__bridge id)kCGImagePropertyGIFDictionary: @{
                                         (__bridge id)kCGImagePropertyGIFLoopCount: @0 // 0 means loop forever
                                         }
                                 };

CFURLRef url = (__bridge CFURLRef)[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];

CGImageDestinationRef dst = CGImageDestinationCreateWithURL(url, kUTTypeGIF, [images count], nil);
CGImageDestinationSetProperties(dst, (__bridge CFDictionaryRef)fileProperties);

for (int i=0;i<[images count];i++)
{
        //load anImage from array
        UIImage * anImage = [images objectAtIndex:i];

        CGImageDestinationAddImage(dst, anImage.CGImage,(__bridge CFDictionaryRef)prep);

}

bool fileSave = CGImageDestinationFinalize(dst);
CFRelease(dst);
if(fileSave) {
    NSLog(@"animated GIF file created at %@", path);
}else{
    NSLog(@"error: no animated GIF file created at %@", path);
}
```

And saving the GIF into Photo Album as well as in NSDocumentDirectory. To save in Photo Album of iPhone, here is the code:

```
ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];

NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:tempPath];

[library writeImageDataToSavedPhotosAlbum:data metadata:nil completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Error Saving GIF to Photo Album: %@", error);
    } else {
        // TODO: success handling
        NSLog(@"GIF Saved to %@", assetURL);

        success(tempPath);
    }
}];
```

[HJImagesToGIF](https://github.com/HarrisonJackson/HJImagesToGIF) was big help, as well as [this gist](https://gist.github.com/mayoff/4969104)!

**UPDATE:**

On analysing the Image Header of 2 GIFs:
1- Image Header: **GIF89a** - downloaded through safari and shows GIF label in twitter app
2- Image Header: **GIF87a** - Created through code, doesnt show GIF label in twitter app

So the Image Header! hmmm.. how do I change it?

Comment: Can you please describe me how this work, I have same issue..

Answer (score 7):

Ok so solved the issue, I am not sure if its the best solution, and would appreciate better solutions from anyone!

The problem was indeed related to the image header of the GIFs which I created through Code.
I took a GIF89a header GIF and copied the header (first 6 bytes) and replaced my GIF's image header with it. Working fine now on twitter as well as email and iMessage.

Here is the code I used:

```
NSMutableData *gifData = [NSMutableData dataWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"1.gif" ofType:nil]]; // GIF89a file
NSMutableData *data = [NSMutableData dataWithContentsOfFile:path]; // My created GIF file 
NSMutableData *gif89 = [NSMutableData dataWithData:[gifData subdataWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, 6)]]; // the first 6 bytes we needed (or the Header)
[data replaceBytesInRange:NSMakeRange(0, 6) withBytes:gif89.bytes]; // replace the header.. Voila!
```

Comment: Could you please explain in details how exactly do you get the header and do bytes swapping.

Comment: Updated my answer with Code sample

Comment: I did just as you said, and it works ok everywhere except Facebook and Twitter. Still have still images there, any thoughts?

Comment: AFAIK facebook doesnt show animating GIFs in posts, but twitter does!

you dont see a 'GIF' mark on the images on twitter? as i have shown in the screenshots. 

check the header of the file on some online tool. Let me give you a URL.

Comment: So I tried this: I sent gif to my email. Then downloaded on my mac and tried to post it through tweetbot and it was animating (same with web client). Same image shared through UIActivityViewController -> Twitter, doesn't animate.

Comment: Now FB is allowing Gif images but there is a problem, if you directly upload   pic or share with fb library it doesnt animate, when u post its url it animates. its strange.

Comment: This is brilliant hack! FYI, the header is just ASCII data. Like for GIF89a the header is exactly that "GIF89a" string.

Comment: :D this is interesting, i should have worked with ASCII rather the data! thanks @Rocotilos

Comment: I tired and same thing as @haawa said, changing the header made email sharing works and it's animated, but not Twitter...

Comment: Changing the header did not work for me either. I also noticed that this is only an issue when you have the Twitter app installed. If you delete the app or use the simulator, then the GIF will be animated!