# How to change file's Header Bytes (Signature)?

Tags: ios, file, file-io

I am creating a Animated GIF image, although GIF support for multiple images in the file, as well as support for animation, on its analysis of HEX Signature, i found out that, it shows **GIF 87a** signature, which is the old GIF format and the signature should have been **GIF 89a**.

So the question is, questions are:

- How can I change HEX Signature of any file?
- Should I change the HEX signature at all? (as my created gifs definitely support mulitple files and animation, it should have had GIF 89a hex, but it does not)
- all of these on iOS!

Thanks everyone!

Comment: You want to do this programmatically?

Comment: @Droppy yes programmatically, as I am creating the GIFs programmatically, need to do any modification as they are created.

Comment: Please show the code you use to write the GIF headers.

Comment: here is the code and explanation of the issue in detail:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24986836/gif-do-not-animate-when-share-on-twitter

Comment: FWIW, hex is a just way to encode numbers, just like decimal or octal. The signature you're talking about is called the header :)

Comment: @toasted_flakes you are right, i used wrong term, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

For my specific problem, Solved it, by replacing the HEX signature (which were the first 6 bytes of the GIF) of a GIF89a file with GIFs i created.

Here is the sample code for replacing the HEX Signatures.

```
NSMutableData *GIF89a = [NSMutableData dataWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"1.gif" ofType:nil]];
NSMutableData *GIF87a = [NSMutableData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
NSMutableData *hexSignature = [NSMutableData dataWithData:[gifData subdataWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, 6)]];
[data replaceBytesInRange:NSMakeRange(0, 6) withBytes:gif89.bytes];
```

I would appreciate better solution from anyone, Thanks! :)

Comment: If you want to optimize solely for speed (and your files are already on disk) use a file-backed `mmap`. This way you don't bring the whole file to memory, only a page.

Comment: Ok, I will definitely try it, thanks for suggestion.